# Equally space divs within a parent div?

Tags: html, css

Should be simple enough. I have a div with a width of 1100px which contains divs of width 300px. I need to space them out equally and clear to the next line below once no more can fit within the 1100px width. Best way to do this? I've never needed to do it.

Comment: Do you have a image to ilustrate what do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. You can use `nth-of-type` to add margin to the middle boxes

```
.background{
  background: black;
  width: 1100px;
  margin: auto
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 20px
}

.box:nth-of-type(3n+2){
  margin: 0 100px 20px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r4jkmsd2/)

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you could use operators in nth-of-type that way

Comment: @TomMaxwell yep very useful. If this is what you were looking for just be sure to check this off as resolved